# Overwrite or rewrite result of a derivation

Tags: nix

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76142628/building-an-android-app-with-bazel-setup-in-a-nix-shell-environment/76233976#76233976) to a previous question, I used a python script to turn the symlinks into hard copies.

Now when using gitlab-ci with a `nixpkgs/nix` image, I ran into `Permission denied` problems, because I couldn't just use `sudo` to overwrite the files of the `androidenv.composeAndroidPackages` derivation.

I figured that I might be able to create a derivation based on the result of the `androidenv.composeAndroidPackages`, so I used that as the `$src`. But it looks like I am not allowed to modify anything inside the directory I copied the `$src` files into, so creating intermediate temp directories resulted in a `Permission denied` error as well.

I  looked into using patches, but as I understood it, I can only patch files and not rewrite the resulting symlinks to directories, like I want to do.

My question for now is, How can I get write access to the copied files, if at all possible, so my python script can run without error?

Following are all relevant files:

**shell.nix**

```hs
with (import <nixpkgs> {});
let
  jdk = jdk11;
  androidsdk = import ./nix/androidsdk.nix;
in
mkShell rec {
  name = "android-shell";

    buildInputs = [
      gnumake
      jdk
      androidsdk
      bazel_4
    ];

  JAVA_HOME = jdk.home;
  ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = "${androidsdk}/libexec/android-sdk";
  ANDROID_HOME = "${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}";
}
```

**nix/android-sdk.nix**

```hs
with (import <nixpkgs> {});
let
  android-composition = import ./android-composition.nix;
in
stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "androidsdk";

  buildInputs = [
    python3Full
  ];

  src = "${android-composition.androidsdk}";

  dontUnpack = true;

  installPhase = ''
    cp -r $src $out
    python ${./androidsdk-fixup.py} "$out/libexec/android-sdk"
  '';
}
```

**nix/androidsdk-fixup.py**

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, os, shutil

ANDROIDSDK_PATH = sys.argv[1]
BUILD_TOOLS_PATH = f'{ANDROIDSDK_PATH}/build-tools'
PLATFORMS_PATH = f'{ANDROIDSDK_PATH}/platforms'

BUILD_TOOLS = [os.path.join(BUILD_TOOLS_PATH, filename) for filename in os.listdir(BUILD_TOOLS_PATH)]
PLATFORMS = [os.path.join(PLATFORMS_PATH, filename) for filename in os.listdir(PLATFORMS_PATH)]

for build_tool in BUILD_TOOLS:
    if os.path.islink(build_tool):
        print(f'build-tool "{os.path.basename(build_tool)}" is a symlink. Copying...')
        link_src = os.readlink(build_tool)
        os.unlink(build_tool)
        shutil.copytree(link_src, build_tool)

for platform in PLATFORMS:
    if os.path.islink(platform):
        print(f'platform "{os.path.basename(platform)}" is a symlink. Copying...')
        link_src = os.readlink(platform)
        os.unlink(platform)
        shutil.copytree(link_src, platform)
```

**nix/android-composition.nix**

```hs
with (import <nixpkgs> {
  config.allowUnfree = true;
  config.android_sdk.accept_license = true;
});

androidenv.composeAndroidPackages {
  platformVersions = ["28" "30" "31"];
  buildToolsVersions = ["30.0.3"];
}
```

Error with `cp -r $src $out`:

```bash
$ nix-shell
this derivation will be built:
  /nix/store/4ql2v7qfc1ksznqh9pr68a2hvm6w0dp0-androidsdk.drv
building '/nix/store/4ql2v7qfc1ksznqh9pr68a2hvm6w0dp0-androidsdk.drv'...
patching sources
configuring
no configure script, doing nothing
building
no Makefile or custom buildPhase, doing nothing
installing
build-tool "30.0.3" is a symlink. Copying...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/nix/store/kwb9vy9qla70phjwb07nq0183zl7x7va-androidsdk-fixup.py", line 16, in <module>
    os.unlink(build_tool)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/nix/store/36axgk04q1l8pbb3c69rrh2xwshg3dqj-androidsdk/libexec/android-sdk/build-tools/30.0.3'
error: builder for '/nix/store/4ql2v7qfc1ksznqh9pr68a2hvm6w0dp0-androidsdk.drv' failed with exit code 1;
       last 10 log lines:
       > configuring
       > no configure script, doing nothing
       > building
       > no Makefile or custom buildPhase, doing nothing
       > installing
       > build-tool "30.0.3" is a symlink. Copying...
       > Traceback (most recent call last):
       >   File "/nix/store/kwb9vy9qla70phjwb07nq0183zl7x7va-androidsdk-fixup.py", line 16, in <module>
       >     os.unlink(build_tool)
       > PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/nix/store/36axgk04q1l8pbb3c69rrh2xwshg3dqj-androidsdk/libexec/android-sdk/build-tools/30.0.3'
       For full logs, run 'nix-store -l /nix/store/4ql2v7qfc1ksznqh9pr68a2hvm6w0dp0-androidsdk.drv'.
```

Error with intermediate directory with

```hs
  installPhase = ''
    mkdir -p $PWD/tmp
    cp -r $src/* $PWD/tmp/
    python ${./androidsdk-fixup.py} "$PWD/tmp/libexec/android-sdk"
    cp -r $PWD/tmp $out
  '';
```

=>

```bash
$ nix-shell
this derivation will be built:
  /nix/store/biy5vdhcahy1bdm60p9ijlkp190bb481-androidsdk.drv
building '/nix/store/biy5vdhcahy1bdm60p9ijlkp190bb481-androidsdk.drv'...
patching sources
configuring
no configure script, doing nothing
building
no Makefile or custom buildPhase, doing nothing
installing
build-tool "30.0.3" is a symlink. Copying...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/nix/store/kwb9vy9qla70phjwb07nq0183zl7x7va-androidsdk-fixup.py", line 16, in <module>
    os.unlink(build_tool)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/build/tmp/libexec/android-sdk/build-tools/30.0.3'
error: builder for '/nix/store/biy5vdhcahy1bdm60p9ijlkp190bb481-androidsdk.drv' failed with exit code 1;
       last 10 log lines:
       > configuring
       > no configure script, doing nothing
       > building
       > no Makefile or custom buildPhase, doing nothing
       > installing
       > build-tool "30.0.3" is a symlink. Copying...
       > Traceback (most recent call last):
       >   File "/nix/store/kwb9vy9qla70phjwb07nq0183zl7x7va-androidsdk-fixup.py", line 16, in <module>
       >     os.unlink(build_tool)
       > PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/build/tmp/libexec/android-sdk/build-tools/30.0.3'
       For full logs, run 'nix-store -l /nix/store/biy5vdhcahy1bdm60p9ijlkp190bb481-androidsdk.drv'.
```

Comment: Yes, you can't overwrite files inside a derivation that was already built; that goes against most of the principles of Nix.  If you copy files from a built derivation they will have permissions that prevent modification, but you can change the permissions on the copy. 
 What is your actual question?  (So far, your post is just a long story.)

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. I don't know why I didn't try changing the permissions, but I just did, and it works like I wanted to. Thanks! I guess "just use chmod" is the answer here.

Comment: cp also has a `--no-preserve=mode` option, but that's not great if there are executables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did now is creating a `buildDir`, copying the files there, running `chmod` on the `buildDir` and then copying the resulting files to `$out`.

Here's the corresponding `.nix`-file.

*nix/androidsdk.nix*

```hs
with (import <nixpkgs> {});
let
  android-composition = import ./android-composition.nix;
in
stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "androidsdk";

  buildInputs = [
    python3Full
  ];

  src = "${android-composition.androidsdk}";

  dontUnpack = true;

  buildPhase = ''
    buildDir=$PWD/android-composition
    mkdir $buildDir

    cp -r $src/* $buildDir

    chmod -R +w "$buildDir/libexec/android-sdk"
    python ${./androidsdk-fixup.py} "$buildDir/libexec/android-sdk"
  '';

  installPhase = ''
    cp -r $buildDir $out
  '';
}
```